# Bootstrap datepicker not working in external page modal popup in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datepicker, bootstrapping

The below code to display "Add Date" button and by clicking that button it will display the modal with external mvc view. "CheckDateShow" is the view page here.

```
<div class="add-dependent left">
   <a href="../Home/CheckDateShow" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalAdd">  
       <img src="../../Reskin/images/banificiary.png" alt="">
       <span class="green-btn">Add Date</span>
   </a>
</div>
```

The modal where it would bind given in below code and it exists in same page.

```
<div class="modal fade dependents-modal" id="myModalAdd">   
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">


        </div> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

The "CheckDateShow" page contains the below code:-

```
<html>
<head>    
<title>..:: Company Logo ::..</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/style.css">      
<script src="../../js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="../../js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="../../js/custom.js"></script>
</head>
<body>             
<div>
                <ul>                      
                  <li>
                    <label for="">Date of Birth:</label> 
                    <div class="input-data date">
                      <input type="text" class="input-type datepicker">
                      <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                      <span class="red">*</span>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                </ul>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now by loading this it is showing only a textbox control, but in reality it should display a datepicker rightside of textbox and we can be able to choose a date.

Please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: You were right, yours should still work though because mine works either way

Comment: You know what I reckon you should check if your reference to the `bootstrap.css` and `bootstrap.js` are right

Comment: The same functionality working here if <a href="#user-detail" data-toggle="modal">Add Date</a>  because here the "user-detail" available in same page. The problem when calling external Url.

Comment: are both on the same page?

Comment: When I'm providing href="#user-detail" then here contains a div with id="user-detail" and this is same page. But when I'm providing href="../Home/CheckDateShow" then "CheckDateShow" is a separate view page. So that I'm calling this as external page as given the code in question.